# DB2 cascade delete command?

Tags: sql, syntax, db2

Is there a special syntax to execute a cascade delete on DB2 or is it only possible to create "cascadable" tables by defining them with the "ON DELETE CASCADE" option?

What I am trying to achieve is delete other table rows based on a same foreign key when I delete that key, but this is done on an already existing and data-filled database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you stated, you either have to **create FKs with an `ON DELETE CASCADE`** clause or to **pre-delete the other rows** with a subselect-delete.

So, if you don't have an `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause you have to do

```
DELETE FROM ORDERS_ITEMS WHERE ORDER_ID in (
    SELECT ORDER_ID FROM ORDERS WHERE STATUS = 'Canceled'
);

DELETE FROM ORDERS_ADDRESS WHERE ORDER_ID in (
    SELECT ORDER_ID FROM ORDERS WHERE STATUS = 'Canceled'
);

DELETE FROM ORDERS WHERE STATUS = 'Canceled';
```

It is simple, but is somewhat redundant so you may use the [WITH](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db29.doc.apsg/db2z_createcte.htmstatement) statement.

If the request to select the required rows is quite big, and **if you don't have** at least a **RR isolation level**, you may have to use a [**TEMPORARY table**](http://www.cs.newpaltz.edu/~pletcha/DB/db2_TempTables.html) :

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TMP_IDS_TO_DELETE (ID BIGINT) NOT LOGGED;

INSERT INTO SESSION.TMP_IDS_TO_DELETE (ID)
    SELECT ORDER_ID FROM ORDERS WHERE STATUS = 'Canceled';

DELETE FROM ORDERS_ITEMS WHERE ORDER_ID in (
   SELECT ID FROM SESSION.TMP_IDS_TO_DELETE
);


DELETE FROM ORDERS_ADDRESS WHERE ORDER_ID in (
    SELECT ID FROM SESSION.TMP_IDS_TO_DELETE
);

DELETE FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDER_ID in (
    SELECT ID FROM SESSION.TMP_IDS_TO_DELETE
);
```

This way you are sure that you will **delete the same rows in each table**, and a FK error will still fire up if you miss something. Per default, the temporary table will empty itself on commit.